# Frequency with repeated measures

Tags: repeated-measures, categorical-data, frequency

I did an experiment in which I group objects based on machine learning. I then tested whether people group them in the same way.

Each subject (I had 30 subjects) watches 8 sets of 3 objects. In each set, 2 of the objects are grouped together according to ML, and one is not (subjects are unaware of this). For each set, subjects are asked to group 2 of the three objects that to them are the most similar.

I guess I cannot use chi-squared, because the measure is repeated (8 times) for each subject. The McNemar's Test is usually used in different settings.

What would be the most appropriate measure?

According to [this](http://staff.washington.edu/tabrooks/599.course/BadChiSquare.html), I'd go for t-test, with $\text{mu}=\frac{1}{3}$, but:

1. if the Shapiro–Wilk test gives me that the distribution is not normal, I couldn't proceed with t-test;
2. I don't know if there's something better suited to the problem.